# Effect on performance of lowering resolution in the settings vs performance of real physical laptop already having that resolution

Tags: performance, optimization, graphics, screen-resolution, cpu-architecture

I'm sorry that the title is confusing, but it is so complicated I couldn't make a good title. I don't know if it's in the correct stackexchange subdivision in the first place, if it's in the wrong forum, please migrate it!

HD = 1920x1080, UHD = 3840x2160

Let's say I buy a laptop with UHD screen and for example NVIDIA GeForce 980M card. Some games may run slow because the screen is very big.

Now I change the graphics settings for a lower resolution from UHD to like HD. Will changing from an UHD to HD in the graphics settings make the laptop's performance equally fast to the performance of another laptop that is physically build with HD screen, or will it still run a bit slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically impossible to give an exact answer to this without measuring the exact computers, but either way, you are not going to notice any difference.

If they cost the same, the difference would be from the laptop manufacturer spending their hardware budget on a higher resultion screen rather than a better processor etc.

If the software and hardware is the same, except for the screen, you wouldn't notice any difference except the price of the computer.

Comment: Thank you! You really helped!